# Where should one go to learn about triangulated categories?

Tags: ct.category-theory, triangulated-categories, higher-category-theory

Lurie's book, higher topos theory describes a new notion of a triangulated category, which is apparently much more natural than the usual definition. Obviously by now a great deal of work has been done on triangulated categories, has anyone translated any of this work into this new language?

That is should one go straight to his book, or become reasonably acquainted with triangulated categories first, in the hope that by then people will have become more familiar with that language by then?

Comment: You should probably become familiar with the derived category. I recommend The Heart of Cohomology by Kato for this, but there are a number of other books.

Comment: I should add that I made the mistake of trying to learn triangulated categories before having any experience even with hypercohomology (which is itself probably important to know before learning about the derived category...)

Comment: «Corrupted shadow» is a description that can be avoided with much gain.

Comment: For triangulated and derived categories I would recommend the relevant sections in the book "Sheaves on manifolds" by Schapira and Kashiwara.

Comment: In fact, if you only care about triangulated categories and can read French, then Verdier's original thesis is also quite nice (available on the home page of G. Maltsinoitis).  Of course it covers derived categories also but I found the exposition a bit confusing in some places.

Comment: Of course, there's also Neeman's book, available online: http://hopf.math.purdue.edu/Neeman/triangulatedcats.pdf

Comment: @Suarez-alvarez: I too would avoid 'corrupted shadows' :). To everyone else, thanks for the suggestions
 

Comment: @Davidac87: according to wikipedia 'Hyperhomology is no longer used much: since about 1970 it has been largely replaced by the roughly equivalent concept of a derived functor between derived categories', but does this mean hypercohomology is still useful? Wouldn't it be simply the dual of hyper-homology. Is it best, a la other peoples comments, simply to go to the derived category, and avoid hyper- co/homology?

Comment: Kashiwara&Schapira's "Categories and sheaves" also discusses derived and triangulated categories. I can't compare with Adeel Ahmad Khan's suggestion because I didn't read the other book.

Comment: Stable (∞,1)-categories are discussed at the beginning of Higher Algebra, not Higher Topos Theory. (I mention this in case anybody tries to look for them after reading your question here.)

Answer (score 4):

It is not necessary but it is a good idea to learn about more "classical" definitions. A good place is the stacks project: 
http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/browse
where you will find a chapter on derived categories.

Behrang Noohi has written a nice survey:"Lectures on derived and triangulated categories" available on arXiv.